# Python Flask : How to convert a dictionary object to json?

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm fairly new to Python. So I have a REST API based on Flask.So I have a dictionary as listed below :

```
dict = {'left': 0.17037454, 'right': 0.82339555, '_unknown_': 0.0059609693}
```

I need to add this to my json response object which is like this :

```
message = {
                            'status': 200,
                            'message': 'OK',
                            'scores': dict 
                        }
                resp = jsonify(message)
                resp.status_code = 200
                print(resp)
                return resp
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
....\x.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: 0.027647732 is not JSON serializable
```

Can some one help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: This comment comes rather late but I would assume, using `dict` as a variable name is a bad idea and could potentially be understood by python as the type name, not as the dictionary and it probably cannot serialize native types to json. Just saying, because no one of the other answers explicitly said it.

Answer (score 6):

The code runs fine for me. Look at the following example server code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    d = {'left': 0.17037454, 'right': 0.82339555, '_unknown_': 0.0059609693}
    message = {
        'status': 200,
        'message': 'OK',
        'scores': d
    }
    resp = jsonify(message)
    resp.status_code = 200
    print(resp)
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And the following curl returns fine:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
{
  "message": "OK", 
  "scores": {
    "_unknown_": 0.0059609693, 
    "left": 0.17037454, 
    "right": 0.82339555
  }, 
  "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Doing `json.dumps` on `dict` and then `jsonify(message)` will `jsonify` the `dict` twice, are you sure that's the right way to do things?

Comment: @ThatBird updated

Comment: It's likely that your updated example will not work without `json.dumps`

Answer (score 0):

This error is seen when you try to jsonify something which is not a pure python dictionary. So simply use pure python objects, which are easily translated to JSON.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    dict_obj = {
        'left': 0.17037454, 
        'right': 0.82339555, 
        '_unknown_': 0.0059609693
    }
    message = {
        'status': 200,
        'message': 'OK',
        'scores': dict_obj
    }
    resp = jsonify(message)
    resp.status_code = 200
    print(resp)
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Its a pretty simple code.

When you hit `localhost:5000` in your browser after running this code, you see this output

```
{
  "message": "OK", 
  "scores": {
    "_unknown_": 0.0059609693, 
    "left": 0.17037454, 
    "right": 0.82339555
  }, 
  "status": 200
}
```

I have used `Flask==1.0.2` here.

Few observations:

1. Don't use `dict` as a variable name. Its a python keyword.
2. Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards while writing the code.
3. Don't keep trailing whitespaces in the code.

Comment: It isn't working if my dictionary object is created dynamically.
 # Sort to show labels in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-num_top_predictions:][::-1]
    result = {}
    for node_id in top_k:
      human_string = labels[node_id]
      score = predictions[node_id]
      result[human_string] = score   

print(type(result))
It prints <class 'dict'>